# No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: msbuild visualstudio vstest Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild

I just upgraded to TFS 2017 and deployed an agent and created a new build. I am getting the following error when building:

No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
msbuild
visualstudio
vstest
Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1

I have tried install Visual Studio 2017 Pro, updating the agent, installing build tools, restarting the Agent service, restarting the service, unregistered and registered the Agent. None of these steps have helped.

Comment: And to clarify, my one agent is in the Defualt pool.

Comment: What version is the agent?

Comment: The agent version is 2.112.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and set up a new server, installed Visual Studio, and then installed the agent and now i am up and running.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when upgrading from TFS2015.2 to TFS2017 RTM. You need to delete the old agent on the build server & re-download the new agent from "Agent Queues" to rectify this error.

Comment: I upgraded from 2013 and did not have an agent previously.

Answer (score 0):

In my case other builds were working but I kept getting the error on the newly created build definition. I created a template from existing build. Recreated new build using the custom template